# Finding torque due to normal force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

> A cubical block of mass $m$ and edge length $a$ slides down a rough inclined plane of inclination $\alpha$ radian with a uniform speed. Find the torque of the normal force acting on the block about its center.

On the back of the book the answer is $\frac{1}{2} mga \sin(\alpha)$.

I have done the basic steps like the force of friction $f=mg\sin(\alpha)$ and the normal reaction is $n=mg\cos(\alpha)$. Also as the object is only slipping so net torque $=0$ or $T(N)+T(F)=0$ now if we calculate $T(F)$ question will be solved and even though I have determined the force of friction but what distance should I take and why?

Comment: Have you asked your instructor for help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image][image: Inclined system]
The block moves down the inclined with uniform speed. Therefore,
$$
F_f = mgsin\alpha\space,
$$
Due to symmetry as you said above gravity will produce no ***torque***.
Now the only left-over forces are ***Normal*** and ***Friction*** which will produce torque.
$$
T\space_n\space_e\space_t=T_N+T_F\space,
$$
But the block doesn't roll which means there is no ***net torque*** to provide ***angular acceleration*** . Therefore,
$$
T\space_n\space_e\space_t=T_N+T_F\space=0,
$$
$$
T_N=-T_F
$$
$$
T_N=-F(a/2)
$$
$$
T_N=-(a/2)mgsin\alpha\space\space(i.e\space clockwise)
$$
$$
Magnitude\space of\space T_N=(a/2)mgsin\alpha
$$

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on how you got the value of T(F)

Comment: @Freelancer We have already found that 
$$
Frictional\space Force \space=mgsin\alpha
$$
and it is given that the block slides down with uniform speed.Therefore we can say that the forces are balanced i.e the gravitational and frictional force.
$$
mgsin\alpha=\mu mgcos\alpha=F_f
$$

Comment: I meant how you got a/2 here.

Comment: @Freelancer Did you see the pic above, it is the position of COM in a cube, To find torque simply do F X R. i.e. F(a/2)

Comment: But was frictional force only acting on the particles near the edge !! I think it was acting on all the pertickes but still you are calculating torque about centre and taking distance as a/2

Comment: Or I should say assuming that friction acts only on the cornermost point !!

Comment: Well then on what basis did you take this assumption.

Comment: @Freelancer You can still apply this logic, The net frictional force is acting towards the center of the edge, though it is acting on all particles